# arreglos como parametros en c++ sin crear variable

Tags: c++

tengo una duda con respecto a los parametros, tengo el siguiente programa:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int sum(int a[], int b){
    int c=0;
    for(int i=0; i<b; i++){
        c += a[i];
    }
    return c;
}

int main(){
    int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int b = sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);
    cout << sum(a, b) << endl; //----------
    return 0;
}
```

la funcion `sum` toma los valores adentro de arreglo y los suma.
lo que quiero saber es si puedo llamar al arreglo por valor y no por referencia, o sea, cambiar `sum(a, b)` por `sum({1,2,3,4,5}, b)` sin tener que crear la variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Lo que quiero saber es si puedo llamar al arreglo por valor y no por referencia, o sea, cambiar `sum(a, b)` por `sum({1,2,3,4,5}, b)` sin tener que crear la variable.

No, no puedes. Los arreglos no se pueden pasar por valor ya que como parámetro decaen a puntero, podemos verlo en este ejemplo:

```
void pasa_arreglo(int arreglo[5])
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    pasa_arreglo(a);

    return 0;
}
```

El código anterior muestra:

> ```
> void pasa_arreglo(int *)
> ```

Por lo que si intentamos crear y llamar la función `sum` pasando un arreglo por valor:

```
int sum(int a[5], int b)
{
    int c{};
    for (int i = 0; i != b; ++i)
        c += a[i];
    return c;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << sum({1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 5) << '\n'
    return 0;
}
```

Recibimos el siguiente error:

> ```
> error: no matching function for call to 'sum'
> << sum({6, 7, 8, 9, 0}, 5);
>    ^~~
> note: candidate function not viable: cannot convert initializer list argument to 'int *'
> int sum(int a[5], int b)
>     ^
> ```

El arreglo pasado por valor, decae a puntero y no puedes usar una lista de inicialización para inicializar un puntero. Pero, al contrario de lo que crees **pasando el arreglo como referencia constante** solucionas el problema:

```
int sum(const int (&a)[5])
{
    int c{};
    for (const auto &v : a)
        c += v;
    return c;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << sum({1, 2, 3, 4, 5}) << '\n'
    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU/LasJAFF3P/YoLBc3QCH25idGNWOjGlhIXxcpwmaQykMyEeWQT/PY0U6zF7u45nNeVbTuTNenjMNwoLetQVpgr47ytqFkBKO3RhSaRRjuPESUT4vv5gUMPLGLZnxbAvozFs4iCNzjpMEPiwJjE2yV2o8RWPliNcgEngM6oEltyJMja6libJGad799458sskyZ4zHMU4u19UxQf4nm3XRcvr1shIj391NOfxOhvSOnksoz2B1xif5/iQ4qPKT6lOB@3ArvqJR6pq6r48D8b/@u6fHI39g7DNw)</kbd>. Si quieres que no exista límite en la cantidad de elementos, usa una plantilla:

```
template <unsigned S>
int sum(const int (&a)[S])
{
    int c{};
    for (const auto &v : a)
        c += v;
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero me quedo una duda, ¿que es una referencia constante?

Comment: Una referencia (`&`) marcada como de sólo lectura o constante (`const`).

Answer (score 2):

A partir de C++11, puedes usar [`std::initializer_list< >`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

int sum( std::initializer_list< int > a ){
  int c = 0;

  for( int value : a ) {
    c += value;
  }

  return c;
}

int main( ) {
  std::cout << sum( { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } ) << '\n';
    
  return 0;
}
```

Observa que de esta forma **no puedes** utilizar el operador de indirección `[]`: has de *recorrer* tu lista de números usando iteradores; lo cual, en unión con los [*range-based-for*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), realmente hacen el código mucho mas fácil de escribir y leer.

Observa también que ambos usos **no son equivalentes**. Si la función espera un puntero, no puedes pasarle un `initializer_list`. Y viceversa. Aunque esto es simple de solucionar usando la sobrecarga de funciones:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

int sum( std::initializer_list< int > a ){
  int c = 0;

  for( int value : a ) {
    c += value;
  }

  return c;
}

int sum( int *ptr, size_t count ) {
  int c = 0;

  for( int idx = 0; idx < count; ++idx ) {
    c += ptr[idx];
  }

  return c;
}

int main( ) {
  std::cout << sum( { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } ) << '\n';

  int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

  std::cout << sum( arr, sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( arr[0] ) ) << '\n';
    
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Una forma de resolver tu duda es usando funciones con argumentos variables:

Necesitas incluir la cabecera `cstdarg` . Puedes usar todos los parámetros conocidos, y al final poner los puntos suspensivos `...`, que serán sustituidos por los desconocidos.

Una limitación es que tienes que indicarle el nº de parámetros que van a ir. Esto se puede hacer usando uno de los parámetros como información, o poniendo un valor al final que indique que ya no tiene que seguir considerando más parámetros. También tiene que haber un parámetro "normal", no se pueden poner sólo los puntos suspensivos.

Pongo las dos versiones. En `sumarA` el parámetro conocido es el primer sumando, y se pone `nullptr`para indicar que ya no hay que seguir. En la segunda versión `sumarB`, el parámetro conocido indica el nº de sumandos, y se usará para iterar sobre los parámetros desconocidos.

Es necesario que incluyas las macros `va_list`, `va_start` y `va_end`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>
using namespace std;

int sumarA(int a, ...);
int sumarB(int elementos, ...);

int main()
{
    cout<<sumarA(1, 2, nullptr)<<endl;
    cout<<sumarA(3, 4, 5, nullptr)<<endl;
    cout<<sumarB(2, 3, 4)<<endl;
    cout<<sumarB(3, 1, 5, 8)<<endl;

    return 0;
}

int sumarA(int a, ...)
{
    va_list p;
    va_start(p, a);
    int arg;
    int suma = a;

    while ((arg = va_arg(p, int)))
    {
        suma+=arg;
    }
    va_end(p);
    return suma;
}

int sumarB(int elementos,...)
{
    va_list p;
    va_start(p, elementos);
    int suma = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<elementos;i++)
    {
        suma+=va_arg(p, int);
    }
    va_end(p);
    return suma;
}
```

http://c.conclase.net/curso/?cap=020b#PAR_VARIABLES

o

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/va_arg/